# Python: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.9

Cuando intento ejecutar el programa me aparece el error de:

> line 26, in 
> if map_objets[POSITION_X] == coordinate_x and map_objets[POSITION_Y] == coordinate_y:
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

y como soy un aprendiz autodidacta me encuentro sin maneras de buscar una posible solución que sirva a mi caso.

```
import os
import readchar

POSITION_X = 0
POSITION_Y = 0
MAP_WIDTH = 20
MAP_HEIGHT = 15

my_position = [4, 5]

map_objets = [[1, 3], [5, 8], [8, 9]]

while True:
    # Draw_map
    print("+" + "-" * MAP_WIDTH * 3 + "+")

    for coordinate_y in range(MAP_HEIGHT):
        print("|", end="")
        for coordinate_x in range(MAP_WIDTH):

            char_to_draw = " "
            objet_in_cel = None

            for map_objets in map_objets:
                if map_objets[POSITION_X] == coordinate_x and map_objets[POSITION_Y] == coordinate_y:
                    char_to_draw = "o"
                    objet_in_cel = map_objets

            if my_position[POSITION_X] == coordinate_x and my_position[POSITION_Y] == coordinate_y:
                char_to_draw = "@"

                if objet_in_cel:
                    map_objets.remove(objet_in_cel)
            print(" {} ".format(char_to_draw), end="")
        print("|")
    print("+" + "-" * MAP_WIDTH * 3 + "+")

    # ask user where he wants to move

    direction = readchar.readchar()

    if direction == "w":
        my_position[POSITION_Y] -= 1
        my_position[POSITION_Y] %= MAP_HEIGHT
    elif direction == "s":
        my_position[POSITION_Y] += 1
        my_position[POSITION_Y] %= MAP_HEIGHT
    elif direction == "a":
        my_position[POSITION_X] -= 1
        my_position[POSITION_X] %= MAP_WIDTH
    elif direction == "d":
        my_position[POSITION_X] += 1
        my_position[POSITION_X] %= MAP_WIDTH
    elif direction == "q":
        break
        
    os.system('clear')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema radica en esta linea

```
for map_objets in map_objets:
```

Ya que estas nombrando a la **variable de iteración** igual que tu **variable original**

Y esto ocasiona lo siguiente

```
map_objets = [[1, 3], [5, 8], [8, 9]]
for map_objets in map_objets:
    ....

//Primera iteración = [1, 3]
//Segunda iteración = [5, 8]
//Tercera iteración = [8, 9]
```

Pero después de la tercera, como reasignaste el `map_objets` real `[[1, 3], [5, 8], [8, 9]]` al `map_objets` de iteración, ahora tu `maps_objects` ahora es el último iterador, es decir `map_objets= [8, 9]` por lo que al volver a enter ahora itera sobre este arreglo

Es decir

map_objets = [8, 9]
for map_objets in map_objets:
....

```
Primera iteración = 8
```

Por lo que al intentar hacer esto

```
if map_objets[POSITION_X] == coordinate_x
```

en realidad estaba intentando hacer esto `8[POSITION_x]`

La solución

Solo cambia el nombre de la variable.

```
for map_objets_tmp in map_objets:
    if map_objets_tmp[POSITION_X] == coordinate_x and map_objets_tmp[POSITION_Y] == coordinate_y:
        char_to_draw = "o"
        objet_in_cel = map_objets_tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola si validas el error object is not subscriptable quiere indicar esa variable es incompatible con lo que quieres realizar

Intenta lo siguiente de esta manera evitas ese error y das mas legibilidad al codigo

```
        for x in map_objets:
            if map_objets[POSITION_X] == coordinate_x and map_objets[POSITION_Y] == coordinate_y:
                char_to_draw = "o"
                objet_in_cel = x
```